# syntax error on my trigger code

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, mysql-workbench

what is the problem with my syntax?
i dont´t understand why mysql is showing me an error?

```
create trigger TriggerEquipmentChange on equipment
after insert, delete, update

as
begin

insert into equipment_change (LastUpdate)
values (current_timestamp())

end
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: need a semicolon after the insert statement and at the end?

Comment: @Mureinik this is my errorcode: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'on equipment after insert, delete, update  as begin  insert into equipment_chang' at line 1 0.000 sec

Comment: @dstudeba  this is my errorcode: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'on equipment after insert, delete, update as begin insert into equipment_chang' at line 1 0.000 sec

Answer (score 0):

From the [mysql docu](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-trigger.html):

> CREATE
>       [DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]
>       TRIGGER trigger_name
>       trigger_time trigger_event
>       ON tbl_name FOR EACH ROW
>       trigger_body
>
> trigger_time: { BEFORE | AFTER }
>
> trigger_event: { INSERT | UPDATE | DELETE }

I am not so sure that you can have more than one `trigger_event` in the same trigger creation statement. You may need three triggers for the three events. Also I think the `trigger_body` must be proper SQL statements ending in `;`

The order in which you put the table and the time is wrong also.

Finally, I think you miss out the `FOR EACH ROW` part of the trigger definition.

Try something like this (note this is out of my head and not tested):

```
CREATE TRIGGER TriggerEquipmentChange 
       AFTER INSERT ON equipment 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
  INSERT INTO equipment_change (LastUpdate)
       VALUES (current_timestamp());
END
```

Don't forget to set the DELIMITER to something else than `;` before issuing the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement:

```
DELIMITER ||
CREATE TRIGGER TriggerEquipmentChange 
       AFTER INSERT ON equipment 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
  INSERT INTO equipment_change (LastUpdate)
       VALUES (current_timestamp());
END||
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: @liksch hey thx for your reply but it is still not working i tried your code and now the "END" ist red lined and it says : extreneaous input found - expected end statement :/ .. i don´t understand

Comment: with the delimiter there is nothing more red underlined... but now i get this error:  Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER' at line 8 0.016 sec   @luksch

Comment: When you change the DELIMITER, you need to end the CREATE TRIGGER statement with that new delimiter!

Answer (score 0):

this one worked but i can just get one action like update, insert or delete ...

CREATE TRIGGER TriggerEquipmentChange 
       AFTER INSERT ON equipment 
FOR EACH ROW

INSERT INTO equipment_change (LastUpdate)
       VALUES (current_timestamp());

Comment: This works, since your ```trigger_body``` is a one line statement. There is no  other solution I think than creating 3 trigger.